# Connect-ExchangeOnline UnAuthorized

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm working on updating our PowerShell scripts to use more secure connection methods. When I try, I get an error that says "UnAuthorized"

> PS X:> Connect-ExchangeOnline -AppId $clientId -CertificateThumbprint $thumbPrint -Organization $organization          UnAuthorized
> At C:\Program
> Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ExchangeOnlineManagement\3.0.0\netFramework\ExchangeOnlineManagement.psm1:730 char:21
>
> - throw $_.Exception;
> - 
> - CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], UnauthorizedAccessException
>
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnAuthorized

Is what I highlighted in the following screenshot what I'm supposed to use for the organization parameter?
[snip]

How do I fix the UnAuthorized error?

Thanks

Comment: First, yes the `Organization` parameter uses your tenant name. Second, there's not enough supporting information for us to troubleshoot this for you. Take a look at [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/app-only-auth-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#step-5-assign-azure-ad-roles-to-the-application) for the requirements. Third, I'm not sure you want to include the identifying information in your image (tenant name, tenant ID, organization). If I had to guess, your application is missing one of the permissions or roles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with *@scottwtang*, you will get **unauthorized** error if your application don't have required roles and permissions.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I used **below script** from your previous question to generate certificate:

```
$CN = "GraphApp" 
$cert=New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=$CN" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec Signature -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(5)
$Thumbprint = $Cert.Thumbprint
Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\my\$Thumbprint | Export-Certificate -FilePath $env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\GraphApp.cer
Write-Output "$Thumbprint <- Copy/paste this (save it)"
```

**Output:**

[image]

Now I uploaded this **certificate** to Azure AD application like below:

[image]

For **`$organization`** parameter, you need to pass your domain name. You can find that here:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Overview -> Primary domain***

[image]

When I ran the below script to connect **Exchange Online**, I got **`Access denied`** error like this:

```
$clientId="47xxxd8-8x2x-4xxx-bxx7-30cxxxxx8"
$thumbPrint="E4A0F6C6B85EBFxxxxxCD91B5803F88E5"
$organization="xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"

Connect-ExchangeOnline -AppId $clientId -CertificateThumbprint $thumbPrint -Organization $organization
```

**Output:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you need to add **`API permission`** and **`Directory`** role to your application:

[image]

Make sure to **grant admin consent** for the added permission as below:

[image]

Now I added **Exchange Administrator** role to my application like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Roles and administrators -> Exchange administrator -> Add assignment***

[image]

It may take **few minutes** to assign role successfully as below:

[image]

Now I connected to **Exchange Online** by running script again and ran sample command  `Get-EXOMailbox -PropertySets Archive` to verify it and got **response** successfully like below:

```
$clientId="47xxxd8-8x2x-4xxx-bxx7-30cxxxxx8"
$thumbPrint="E4A0F6C6B85EBFxxxxxCD91B5803F88E5"
$organization="xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"

Connect-ExchangeOnline -AppId $clientId -CertificateThumbprint $thumbPrint -Organization $organization
```

**Output:**

[image]

So, make sure to assign required **roles** and **permissions** for your application to fix the error.

Comment: This is an excellent answer and very well written and formatted. However, it appears to be out of date, as Microsoft has deprecated the legacy APIs (which includes the Exchange Online API described here) in favor of the Microsoft Graph API. Updating the answer for the new API would be amazing.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Exchange.ManageAsApp no longer appears in the Graph API Permissions, so cannot be directly selected in the portal. But you can add the permission by adding the following to the JSON in the Manifest:

```
{
    "resourceAppId": "00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000",
    "resourceAccess": [
        {
            "id": "dc50a0fb-09a3-484d-be87-e023b12c6440",
            "type": "Role"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).